# FSL Installation Failed. Ubuntu 18.0.4

Tags: software-installation

```
Installing FSL into /usr/local/fsl...
[###################                                                                                      ] 18 / 100 % -

ERROR occurred during installation!
    This command returned an error: /usr/local/fsl/bin/mamba env update -n base -f /tmp/tmppFZAPS/fsl-6.0.6.5_linux-64.yml

Removing failed installation directory /usr/local/fsl

FSL installation failed!
```

I tried using:

```
python fslinstaller.py
sudo python fslinstaller.py
```

I changed the user to root and retried:

```
python fslinstaller.py
sudo fslinstaller.py
```

None of it works. I really need to resolve it asap because I want to use FSL.

Comment: Please be aware that Ubuntu 18.04 LTS, which was released in 2018-April (thus the 18.04) had 5 years of *standard* support life, is nearing the end of those five years. You can use `ubuntu-support-status` to confirm if your system is still *supported*. Either way, if the machine is on-line, you should plan to *release-upgrade* asap unless you plan to use ESM/Pro, but please note ESM/Pro releases are not on-topic here when standard support ends.   *EOSS is 30-May-2023 for 18.04, ESM starts 31-May-2023*

Comment: @guiverc According to https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Releases It's supported until June 2023.

Comment: I hadn't seen that page (*since last edit*); it's last day on some official annoucements is 30-May-2023 with ESM starting 31-May-2023, others state 31-May-2023 is the EOSS (*that's actually what we actually use at Ubuntu News as when I sought clarification it was what I was told*), however *bionic* has already been removed from https://packages.ubuntu.com/ as `ubuntu-support-status` reported EOL at 1-May-2023 for most architectures anyway (*though package upgrades have still occurred for i386 despite it being treated as EOL thus far*).  Safest date is 31-May-2023

Comment: @ElderGeek ^  (sorry I forgot to tag)

Comment: @guiverc No argument, but you'll note that either way, it's still on topic today as it's May 25th

Comment: I've not voted for off-topic because of that.. I post mostly as FYI @ElderGeek then move on.  My initial comment says its still on-topic (till 31-May-2023) though I won't vote close till 1-June-2023.

Comment: @guiverc no need to close. Asked and answered. Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't tried this myself, but according to research:

Debian/Ubuntu users should install FSL from the Neurodebian site - http://neuro.debian.net/pkgs/fsl-complete.html and read the setup instructions. As of fsl 5.0 all you need do is add ". /etc/fsl/5.0/fsl.sh" to the end of your . profile file. When you next login you should find the fsl programs are available.

[Note: some package dependencies have non-standard licensing terms – please verify compliance]

Installation process is as follows:

```
wget -O- http://neuro.debian.net/lists/bionic.us-ca.full | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/neurodebian.sources.list
sudo apt-key adv --recv-keys --keyserver hkps://keyserver.ubuntu.com 0xA5D32F012649A5A9
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install fsl-complete
```

For only the  DSFG-compliant software, with permission to use, modify, re-distribute under any conditions:

```
wget -O- http://neuro.debian.net/lists/bionic.us-ca.libre | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/neurodebian.sources.list
sudo apt-key adv --recv-keys --keyserver hkps://keyserver.ubuntu.com 0xA5D32F012649A5A9
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install fsl-complete
```

Comment: This legit works! Thanks for the reply. I have installed FSL through Neurodebian.

Answer (score 0):

FSL installation:

```
useradmin@DEP59365:~/fsl/bin$ python --version
Python 2.7.18
useradmin@DEP59365:~/fsl/bin$ cd .. 
useradmin@DEP59365:~/fsl$ cd ..
useradmin@DEP59365:~$ cd /media/useradmin/Disk2/FSL_installer/
useradmin@DEP59365:/media/useradmin/Disk2/FSL_installer$ sudo python2.7 fslinstaller.py 
FSL installer version: 3.9.0
Press CTRL+C at any time to cancel installation
Running the installer script as root user is discouraged! You should
run this script as a regular user - you will be asked for your administrator
password if required.
Installation log file: /tmp/fslinstaller_0b75Cx.log
Installing FSL implies agreement with the terms of the FSL license - if you
do not agree with these terms, you can cancel the installation by pressing
CTRL+C.
FSL 6.0.7.7 selected for installation
Where do you want to install FSL?
Press enter to install to the default location [/usr/local/fsl/]
FSL installation directory [/usr/local/fsl/]: 
Downloading FSL environment specification from https://fsl.fmrib.ox.ac.uk/fsldow
nloads/fslconda/releases/fsl-6.0.7.7_linux-64.yml...
Installing FSL in /usr/local/fsl
Downloading miniconda from https://github.com/conda-
forge/miniforge/releases/download/23.11.0-0/Mambaforge-23.11.0-0-Linux-
x86_64.sh...
[#############################################################] 80.3 / 80.3 MB \
Installing miniconda at /usr/local/fsl...
[################################################################] 100 / 100 % |
Installing FSL into /usr/local/fsl...
[################################################################] 100 / 100 % -

**FSL successfully installed**

useradmin@DEP59365:/media/useradmin/Disk2/FSL_installer$ echo $FSLDIR
/usr/local/fsl
useradmin@DEP59365:/media/useradmin/Disk2/FSL_installer$ flirt -version
FLIRT version 6.0
useradmin@DEP59365:/media/useradmin/Disk2/FSL_installer$ which imcp
/usr/local/fsl/share/fsl/bin/imcp
```

Answer (score 0):

Apart from above you need to make changes to these files:

**.bashrc**
The following lines to add in:

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/home/useradmin/MonteCarlo/hdf5-install/lib/
export FSLDIR=/home/useradmin/fsl
. ${FSLDIR}/etc/fslconf/fsl.sh
export PATH=${FSLDIR}/bin:${PATH}
export FSLDIR PATH
```

**.profile**
The following lines:

```
# FSL Setup
FSLDIR=/home/useradmin/fsl
PATH=${FSLDIR}/share/fsl/bin:${PATH}
export FSLDIR PATH
. ${FSLDIR}/etc/fslconf/fsl.sh
```

and all the `.csh` files the following lines are commented and have a default location add the following:

```
setenv FSLDIR /home/useradmin/fsl
source $FSLDIR/etc/fslconf/fsl.csh
```

Then restart your computer and open the terminal and check. It works perfect. Installation is done for FSL.